# How to listen to mousemove inside angular material dialog component?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

In my app Ineed to track the mouse movment all the time.

At the app.component.ts file I have placed the following code:

```
ngOnInit() {
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  //foo() 
 });
})
```

Everything works as expected besides inside the dialog.

The dialog is an [Angular Material Dialog component](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api) and the code of creating it like this:

```
openModal() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalComponent, {
      panelClass: 'generic-dialog-container',
      data: {
        header: 'Leave session',
        content:
          'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
        isInfo: false,
      },
    });

    this.dialogSub = dialogRef.componentInstance.isApprove.subscribe(
      isApprove => {
        if (isApprove) {
          this.navigateBack();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

I have tried adding an event listener inside the modal's OnInit - didn't work, Plus I saw that when I add It at the app.component.ts to the document than the listener is added to the body element and wraps the whole app, like this:

[image]

While the dialog is open the Event Listener listens to mouse events at the component in the background (the component who called to open the dialog), but not in the dialog itself.

After closing the dialog and then reopen it, the Event Listener listens to mouse events also inside the dialog as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) to listen for `mousemove` events inside your `ModalComponent`:

```
import { Component, Inject, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

// ...

export class ModalComponent {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ModalComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) { }

  @HostListener('mousemove', ['$event'])
  handleMousemove(event) {
    console.log(`x: ${event.clientX}, y: ${event.clientY}`);
  }
}
```

From within the `mousemove` event handler you can look to emit data as needed perhaps via a shared service, taking advantage of RxJS subjects such as `BehaviorSubjects` that other components/services such as subscribe to.

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ftzcq4) in action. Notice that the `mousemove` event is only triggering when the mouse is in the confines of the modal.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: also works in regular angular component if you want to listen to mouse event in that certain component

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using the document object to add listeners, and instead create an Observable with the `fromEvent` operator. As for the dialog, Angular Material may be interfering with event propagation. Try the Observable, and see what happens.